# VBA custom function that references another worksheet runs correctly in Editor but will not execute when called from sheet

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a custom function to do some tasks, but it seems to be stopping at the start where it is setting the referenced workbook. When I call the function from the VBA editor, it works just fine. When I call the function from a worksheet, it does not work. The true code is as follows:

```
Function getAF(MCID As Variant) As String

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set wb = Workbooks.Open(CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetParentFolderName(ActiveWorkbook.Path) & "\Investment_Prioritisation_Utility.xlsm")
Set ws = wb.Worksheets("assetHierachy")

lastrow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row
inarr = Range(ws.Cells(5, Columns("D").Column), ws.Cells(lastrow, Columns("F").Column))
Searchfor = MCID

On Error GoTo eh
For i = 1 To lastrow
 If inarr(i, UBound(inarr, 2)) = Searchfor Then
  getAF = inarr(i, 2)
  Exit For
 End If
Next i

If IsNumeric(getAF) Then
    getAF = "AF" & getAF
Else
End If
Done:
    Exit Function
eh:
    getAF = "-"
End Function
```

During the debug I have simplified the problem to the following code example, but have left the input and output declaration the same:

```
Function getAF(MCID As Variant) As String
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set wb = Workbooks.Open(CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetParentFolderName(ActiveWorkbook.Path) & "\Investment_Prioritisation_Utility.xlsm")
Set ws = wb.Worksheets("assetHierachy")

return ws.Cells(1, 1)
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your second code uses instruction `Return`, which is not present in `VBA` as far as i know. Are you sure you using the right tag? Shouldn't it be just `VB`?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot open a workbook from a UDF when the `Caller` is a cell. When called from within VBA, then it works.

> UDFs, used in worksheet cells, are not permitted to change the
> structure of the worksheet. This means that a UDF cannot return a
> value to any other cell than the one it is used in and it cannot
> change a physical characteristic of a cell, such as the font color or
> background pattern. In addition, UDFs cannot carry out actions such as
> copying or moving spreadsheet cells. They cannot even carry out some
> actions that imply a change of cursor location, such as an Edit ->
> Find. A UDF can call another function, or even a subroutine, but that
> procedure will be under the same restrictions as the UDF. It will
> still not be permitted to change the structure of the worksheet

(Excel 2003 VBA Programmer's Reference, page 22, Wiley Publishing, Inc)

As a workaround you can trigger this function from within VBA by using event callbacks such as `Worksheet_Change` (for example)